# iOS WKWebView loading PDF data in DarkMode has black background around PDF document

Tags: ios, pdf, wkwebview, ios13

After update to iOS 13 I have experienced problem with loading PDF document into WKWebView.

PDF document was displayed on light gray background in Light Mode. But now in iOS 13 I can change system configuration to Dark Mode. The problem is that PDF loaded in WKWebView gets black background around it instead of this light gray.

Now I don't want to implement Dark Theme for my app and stick with Light Theme all the time in Light Mode and Dark Mode. But this black background doesn't look good.

I also have no idea hot to change this, as this seems to be internal WKWebView implementation

[[image: Light Mode]
[[image: Dark Mode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `UIUserInterfaceStyle` flag with `Light` value in app's `.plist` file to avoid automatically changing colors in a whole app. If you want to do it for certain UIViewController or UIView - just override `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` property with `UIUserInterfaceStyleLight` or `UIUserInterfaceStyleDark` value.